# How to allow access to the module with the appropriate(specify) IP addresses, in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

How to allow access to the module with the appropriate(specify) IP addresses, in Yii2?

I try, but give error:

```
Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException
Setting unknown property: app\modules\getsp\getsp::allowedIPs
```

---

web.php

```
//....
'modules' => [
    'getsp' => [
        'class' => 'app\modules\getsp\getsp',
        'allowedIPs' => ['127.0.0.1', '::1'],
    ],                        
], 
 //...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution might be resolve your issue.

Main-local.php

```
if (!YII_ENV_TEST) {
// configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
$config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
$config['modules']['debug'] = 'yii\debug\Module';

$config['bootstrap'][] = 'getsp';
$config['modules']['getsp'] = 'yii\getsp\Module';
}
```

Main.php

```
'modules' => [
    'getsp' => [
        'class' => 'yii\getsp\Module',
        'allowedIPs' => ['127.0.0.1', '::1', '192.168.1.*', 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX'] // The server machine ip is ex:-(192.168.1.102). or your PC PC ip address ex:-(192.168.1.101) adjust this to your needs
    ],
],
```

Comment: Thanks Erorrs not. But `'allowedIPs' => ['17858569.87.54.197'], === YES ` Or  `'allowedIPs' => ['17858569.8723525235.54235235.197'], === YES `  Any IP = YES

Comment: you can use PC ip address as well.. and if you want to allow all Ips then use  'allowedIPs' => ['*'],